# Getting error when i am uploading app on itunes

Tags: ios, upload, app-store-connect

[image]

I tried so many times. I tried to upload from xcode too. But not working. Please help.

Comment: It is better to copy  some of the error messages as text into the body (or title) of your question. That way other people can find your question if they search for it.

Comment: which Xcode you are using ?

Comment: I am using xcode 7.2.1. @Wolverine

Comment: Try to use install a new xcode 7.2 and try with application loader of that xcode. And also make sure, the account which u are using to UPLOAD and account fom which you used the certificates to sign the app is SAME.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an internet issue. When it was too slow. That's why it was showing timeout again and again. I have changed nothing. Just tried it on another day and it worked.